# Проблема с кодировками в Denwer

Tags: кодировка, denwer

Все файлы кодированы в UTF-8 без BOM. БД в UTF-8. Кодировка страницы указана как UTF-8.
Данные выводимые из БД отображаются нормально. А вот текст из файлов отображается крокозябрами. Если перекодировать файл в ANSI, то отображается нормально.
Разве так оно должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В корне сайта (где лежит `index.php` и другой набор файлов) создай `.htaccess` файл и напиши туда:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить UTF-8 с BOM. У меня почему то браузер отказывался правильно работать без BOM. А если, вам надо отправлять заголовки ( header ), то укажите в файле php.ini output_buffering=On